# Url na jquery está sendo montada de forma errada

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json

tenho uma View chamada FaturarPara, dentro de uma controller de nome Order. Se eu pego a minha jquery e deixo `url: ''`, ele já monta no browser isso:

```
locahost:porta/dominio/order/FaturarPara
```

Vou na jquery e faço isso
`url: /Order/GetDados`, aí no **Network do Chrome** eu pego isso

```
locahost:porta/dominio/order/FaturarPara/Order/GetDados
```

Qualquer configuração que faço, não consigo montar a **url** correta. Esse é meu jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#faturarParaDrop').change(function () {
            var $div = $('#modalPartial'); //exibir a modal
            var idcustomer = $(this).val(); //valor do id da dropdownlist
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Order/GetDados/' + idcustomer,
                type: 'GET',                
                success: function (dados) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(dados));
                },
                error: function (erro) {
                }
            })
        });
    });
```

se pego essa url e jogo no browser, entra na JsonResult

```
locahost:porta/dominio/Order/GetDados/1
```

Como faço para acessar a minha JsonResult na controller?

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi assim:

```
 url: '@Url.Action("GetDados/")' + idcustomer,
```

Answer (score 0):

Você já conseguiu resolver seu problema, mas fica uma dica importante: quando for passar o parâmetro pra url chamada no ajax você pode usar a opção `data:`

No seu exemplo ficaria assim:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#faturarParaDrop').change(function () {
        var $div = $('#modalPartial'); //exibir a modal
        var idcustomer = $(this).val(); //valor do id da dropdownlist
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetDados")',
            type: 'GET',
            data: idcustomer,
            success: function (dados) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(dados));
            },
            error: function (erro) {
            }
        })
    });
});
```

Leia mais na documentação da api: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/